# Typescript: create KeyboardEvent and activate/deactivate it at anytime

Tags: javascript, typescript, event-handling, dom-events, keyboard-events

I would like to be able to handle keyboard events, but also be able to stop/start handling them again as I wish inside my code.

I've been reading through the [MDN Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) about the `KeyboardEvent`, and the way it inherits from `Event` I see I am able to use some useful methods for what I want to achieve such as:

- `event.initEvent`
- `event.preventDefault`

But after some research and trying to put things together I'm struggling and can't end up finding the way to do it.

Just to prove I've tried to figure out how and worked on my solution, I would like to show you what I have so far:

```
class Game {

  private gameOver: boolean = false;
  private timeOfRoundMillis: number = 5 * 1000;
  private keyboardEvent: KeyboardEvent;
  private capturedInput: string[];

  constructor() {}

  public play(): void {
    this.round();
  }

  private round(): void {

    if (!this.gameOver) {

      // I want to start capturing keys
      keyboardEvent.initEvent();

      setTimeout(() => {
        // Now I want to stop capturing keys to process the input
        keyboardEvent.preventDefault();

        this.processPlayerInput();
        this.emptyCapturedInput();
        this.round();
      }, this.timeOfRoundMillis);

    }

  }

  private processPlayerInput(): void {
      // do some stuff with 'capturedInput'
  }

  // I want to call this every time a key is pressed if 
  // capturing keyboard events is active
  private capture(e): void {
     capturedInput.push(e.keyPressed);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After working together we came out with this solution:

```
var keypress = require('keypress');

declare var process: any;

class Game {

  private gameOver: boolean = false;
  private timeOfRoundMillis: number = 5 * 1000;
  private capturedInput: string[];

  constructor() {
     keypress(process.stdin);

     process.openStdin().on('keypress', (key) => {
         // I want to call this every time a key is pressed
         this.capturedInput.push(key);
     });
     process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
  }

  public play(): void {
    this.round();
  }

  private round(): void {

    if (!this.gameOver) {

      setTimeout(() => {
        // Now I want to stop capturing keys to process the input
        this.isCapturingKeys = false;  // need to set it to true when you desire to start capturing again
        this.processPlayerInput();
        this.emptyCapturedInput();
        this.round();
      }, this.timeOfRoundMillis);

    } else {
       process.stdin.pause(); // close stdin events
    }

  }

  private processPlayerInput(): void {
      // do some stuff with 'capturedInput'
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks good, but I am using Typescript on Node.js so `window` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day and it works perfect! :-)

Comment: In order to let the program exit, I edited the solution: `process.stdin.pause();` was missing

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the event is "isComposing" (boolean, true if it is composing)
font: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent